# Using Jenkins on Linux server, isn't run all my tests

Tags: java, jenkins, automated-tests, cucumber

When I run my testes on IntelliJ using same command `mvn clean test`, all test running. But I try to run tests on Jenkins on Linux only 5 of 111 test are running.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/resources/features/"},
        monochrome = true
)

public class CukesFeatureRunnerTest {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void executeBeforeTests() {
      
       Configuration.browser = "chrome";
       Configuration.headless = true;
       Configuration.browserSize = "1600x900";


    }
```

Console output in Jenkins shows  just  'Build was aborted'

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in Jenkins settings. On Configuration, was set timeout in 3 minutes and after this tests was aborted. So to resolve this issue timeout should be canceled

[image]